# Buzzbox SDK For Android

Tags: java, android

Can anyone tell me what kinds of information that Buzzbox collects off of devices?  I am very interested in the SDK as it looks really convienient but I am very concerned about how much data will be skimmed by Buzzbox.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of data that the SDK is collecting is very limited. The SDK is pinging the server with a unique id (that does NOT identify the phone) and mininum phone information, similar to the browser user-agent. It's not collecting any sensitive data. The payload is very small.